# Dynamically add form fields with jquery not posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, tcpdf

I have succeeded in setting up the form and making it work. However I have a issue

I got this Jquery from this

http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/25/

Everything works fine but when I post my data to a tcpdf newly created row didnt send, and mean time I want to add to the database also, please anyone knows the answer much appreciate.
here is my codes

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedSection').length;
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

        var newSection = $('#pq_entry_' + num).clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_' + newNum);

        newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'quantity_' + newNum).attr('name', 'quantity_' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'rcptdelvry_' + newNum).attr('name', 'rcptdelvry_' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'weight_' + newNum).attr('name', 'weight_' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'volume_' + newNum).attr('name', 'volume_' + newNum);

        newSection.insertAfter('#pq_entry_' + num).last();

        $('#btnDel').prop('disabled','');

        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled','');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#btnDel').prop('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled','disabled');
});
</script>
```

***Here is my Html part***

```
<fieldset>
        <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
      <label class="textfield">QUANTITY
      <li><input type="text" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_1"></li>
      <br class="clear">
      </label>

      <label class="textfield">TYPE<br>
   <li><select name="rcptdelvry_1" id="rcptdelvry_1">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <optgroup label="LCL CARGO">
    <option value="PACKAGES">PACKAGES</option>
    <option value="CARTONS">CARTONS</option>
    <option value="BALES">BALES</option>
    <option value="BOX">BOX</option>
    <option value="PALETTES">PALETTES</option>
    <option value="CRATE">CRATE</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="FULL CONTAINER">
    <option value="20' Bulk (with roof hatches)">20' Bulk (with roof hatches)</option>
    <option value="20' Collapsible Flat Rack">20' Collapsible Flat Rack</option>
    <option value="20' Dry">20' Dry</option>
    <option value="20' Flat Rack">20' Flat Rack</option>
    <option value="20' Highvent w/o roof hatches">20' Highvent w/o roof hatches</option>
    <option value="20' Open Top">20' Open Top</option>
    <option value="20' Porthole (conair)">20' Porthole (conair)</option>
    <option value="20' Reefer">20' Reefer</option>
    <option value="20' Tank">20' Tank</option>
    <option value="40' Artificial Tweendeck">40' Artificial Tweendeck</option>
    <option value="40' Collapsible Flat Rack">40' Collapsible Flat Rack</option>
    <option value="40' Dry">40' Dry</option>
    <option value="40' Flat Rack">40' Flat Rack</option>
    <option value="40' High Cube">40' High Cube</option>
    <option value="40' High Cube Reefer">40' High Cube Reefer</option>
    <option value="40' Open Top">40' Open Top</option>
    <option value="40' Starvent (9'6)">40' Starvent (9'6)</option>
    <option value="40' Tank">40' Tank</option>
    <option value="45' High Cube">45' High Cube</option>
    <option value="45' High Cube Reefer">45' High Cube Reefer</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select></li>
      <br class="clear">
      </label>

      <label class="textfield">WEIGHT (kg per container)
      <li><input type="tel" name="weight_1" id="weight_1"></li>
      <br class="clear">
      </label>

       <label class="textfield">VOLUME (cbm):
      <li><input type="tel" name="volume_1" id="volume_1"></li>
      <br class="clear">
      </label>
      </ul>

      </fieldset>
      <input type='button' id='btnAdd' size="15" value='add another row' />
<input type='button' id='btnDel' value='delete row' />
      </div>
      </div>
```

***Here is my tcpdf part***

```
<td width="0" height="0">
 : {$_POST['quantity_1']}X{$_POST['rcptdelvry_1']}{$_POST['quantity_2']}X{$_POST['rcptdelvry_2']}
</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

Submitting your form with a standard 'submit' button will not work in this case.
The submit button does not take the formfields in account that are created after page load.

You'll have to write a submit handler that serializes your data and sends it to the server.

Try something like this:

```
$('#yourFormID').on('submit', function(e) {
    //prevent the default submithandling
    e.preventDefault();
    //send the data of 'this' (the matched form) to yourURL
    $.post('yourURL', $(this).serialize());
});
```

serverside you now have the $_POST variable filled with the keys and values.

You can also inspect the data that is send in firebug or any other webdeveloper tool.

EDIT:

I have altered your fiddle to work with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/67/

I have wrapped a `<form></form>` around your inputs and added a `<input type='submit' />` button

Comment: @DKSan.. thank you for your code, but im wondering where to put this code, cause very less my knowledge about jquery thing.. thnks again

Comment: And some more values adding to the pdf file just fine way, but I cannot figure it out how to send second value in a dynamic elements.

Comment: Just put it after '$(document).ready(function() { //yourCode }' and remember to exchange yourFormID by the actual forms id and yourURL with the url you want to send to.

Comment: I tried your code but It wont open pdf file as i wanted.. hmmmmmmm

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the same problem. Preventing the default but how could we now Post data.

Comment: Jquery post will simply make a post request to the destination specified, it will not change the page or perform any navigation.

Comment: Does this work for <input type="file"> elements? The file type input elements are not serialized for some reasons!

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal have you tried inspecting then $_FILES array on the serverside after posting? Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @DKSan - Thanks for your response, I found the problem, I was breaking my head over it. The <form> tag was not wrapped around the file upload element. Same was with many other <input> elements but these were not dynamically added and probably <form> knew about it, but when <input> file type element was added dynamically even with "for" attribute the form would not pick it up.